# Embedded @XMLElement twice with the same name

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, entity

I have a Person entity that includes two Phone Embeddable objects. Phone has an `@XmlElement` called `type`. This is not mapped to any column in Person entity.

This Phone is embedded twice in the Person entity. When I run the program, it shows the compilation error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: type`. I understand `type` is repeated twice with Phone is embedded twice.

How to override the `@XmlElement` name in each of the Embeds? Or any other way ignore embedding only that element in the Person entity? Any other option?